# GCC misleading indentation warning is disabled from this point onwards?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

When compiling a rather large [C++ project](https://github.com/godotengine/godot), I am getting this message:

> note: -Wmisleading-indentation is disabled from this point onwards, since column-tracking was disabled due to the size of the code/headers

So, a few questions:

- How bad is it that this warning is disabled?
- What kind of things cause this to be disabled? Just the code being too large?
- Is there a way to optimize/fix the code to prevent it from being disabled?
- Is there a way to re-enable it despite the size of the code/headers?
- Is there a way to silence the note about the warning being disabled?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How bad is it that this warning is disabled?

It has zero effect other than the obvious that you won't get warnings for code misleadingly indented from the point where the warning appeared.

> What kind of things cause this to be disabled? Just the code being too large?

[This GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89549)

> Is there a way to optimize/fix the code to prevent it from being disabled?

Sure, but it'll require work that's wasted. Wait for the bugfix in gcc.

> Is there a
>   way to re-enable it despite the size of the code/headers?

It'll most likely re-enable itself if possible (when starting with a new translation unit).

> Is there a
>   way to silence the note about the warning being disabled?

I'd add `-Wno-misleading-indentation` for the time being. You can use also a different compiler if you have one installed.

Example, `clang 8.0.0` does not give that warning:

`scons -j12 platform=x11 use_llvm=yes target=release_debug`

Comment: It doesn't look like they are trying to fix it.

Comment: @DanM. It's not closed and they adjusted the target milestone @ 2020-03-04 so it doesn't look like they have given up :-)

Comment: Yet Jakub Jelinek doesn't see it as a bug.

Comment: @DanM. Indeed, but it's still open and not rejected.